# Custom function be called instead of getfullyear() in java script

Tags: javascript, calendar, datepicker, persian, jomsocial

I want my custom function be called instead of `getfullyear()` in java script how can I do this ? The point is to change a gregorian calendar to jallali in jomsocial.
for example when I write this

```
d=new Date(b.year,b.month,b.date+a);c.set("highlight",JalaliDate[d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()]
```

The result will be `2014/16/7`, I want it to became `1393/6/25`

This is the function that I want to be called 
http://www.farsiweb.info/jalali/jalali.js
or

```
jQuery(function($){
$.datepicker.regional['fa'] = {
    calendar: JalaliDate,
    closeText: 'بستن',
    prevText: 'قبل',
    nextText: 'بعد',
    currentText: 'امروز',
    monthNames: ['فروردین','اردیبهشت','خرداد','تیر','مرداد','شهریور','مهر','آبان','آذر','دی','بهمن','اسفند'],
    monthNamesShort: ['فروردین','اردیبهشت','خرداد','تیر','مرداد','شهریور','مهر','آبان','آذر','دی','بهمن','اسفند'],
    dayNames: ['یکشنبه', 'دوشنبه', 'سه شنبه', 'چهارشنبه', 'پنجشنبه', 'جمعه', 'شنبه'],
    dayNamesShort: ['یک', 'دو', 'سه', 'چهار', 'پنج', 'جمعه', 'شنبه'],
    dayNamesMin: ['ی','د','س','چ','پ','ج','ش'],
    weekHeader: 'ه',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 6,
    isRTL: true,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    calculateWeek: function(date) {
        var checkDate = new JalaliDate(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + (date.getDay() || 7) - 3);
        return Math.floor(Math.round((checkDate.getTime() - new JalaliDate(checkDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTime()) / 86400000) / 7) + 1;
    }};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fa']); });
function JalaliDate(p0, p1, p2) {
var gregorianDate;
var jalaliDate;

if (!isNaN(parseInt(p0)) && !isNaN(parseInt(p1)) && !isNaN(parseInt(p2))) {
    var g = jalali_to_gregorian([parseInt(p0, 10), parseInt(p1, 10), parseInt(p2, 10)]);
    setFullDate(new Date(g[0], g[1], g[2]));
} else {
    setFullDate(p0);
}

function jalali_to_gregorian(d) {
    var adjustDay = 0;
    if(d[1]<0){
        adjustDay = leap_persian(d[0]-1)? 30: 29;
        d[1]++;
    }
    var gregorian = jd_to_gregorian(persian_to_jd(d[0], d[1] + 1, d[2])-adjustDay);
    gregorian[1]--;
    return gregorian;
}

function gregorian_to_jalali(d) {
    var jalali = jd_to_persian(gregorian_to_jd(d[0], d[1] + 1, d[2]));
    jalali[1]--;
    return jalali;
}

function setFullDate(date) {
    if (date && date.getGregorianDate) date = date.getGregorianDate();
    gregorianDate = new Date(date);
    gregorianDate.setHours(gregorianDate.getHours() > 12 ? gregorianDate.getHours() + 2 : 0)
    if (!gregorianDate || gregorianDate == 'Invalid Date' || isNaN(gregorianDate || !gregorianDate.getDate())) {
        gregorianDate = new Date();
    }
    jalaliDate = gregorian_to_jalali([
        gregorianDate.getFullYear(),
        gregorianDate.getMonth(),
        gregorianDate.getDate()]);
    return this;
}

this.getGregorianDate = function() { return gregorianDate; }

this.setFullDate = setFullDate;

this.setMonth = function(e) {
    jalaliDate[1] = e;
    var g = jalali_to_gregorian(jalaliDate);
    gregorianDate = new Date(g[0], g[1], g[2]);
    jalaliDate = gregorian_to_jalali([g[0], g[1], g[2]]);
}

this.setDate = function(e) {
    jalaliDate[2] = e;
    var g = jalali_to_gregorian(jalaliDate);
    gregorianDate = new Date(g[0], g[1], g[2]);
    jalaliDate = gregorian_to_jalali([g[0], g[1], g[2]]);
};

this.getFullYear = function() { return jalaliDate[0]; };
this.getMonth = function() { return jalaliDate[1]; };
this.getDate = function() { return jalaliDate[2]; };
this.toString = function() { return jalaliDate.join(',').toString(); };
this.getDay = function() { return gregorianDate.getDay(); };
this.getHours = function() { return gregorianDate.getHours(); };
this.getMinutes = function() { return gregorianDate.getMinutes(); };
this.getSeconds = function() { return gregorianDate.getSeconds(); };
this.getTime = function() { return gregorianDate.getTime(); };
this.getTimeZoneOffset = function() { return gregorianDate.getTimeZoneOffset(); };
this.getYear = function() { return jalaliDate[0] % 100; };

this.setHours = function(e) { gregorianDate.setHours(e) };
this.setMinutes = function(e) { gregorianDate.setMinutes(e) };
this.setSeconds = function(e) { gregorianDate.setSeconds(e) };
this.setMilliseconds = function(e) { gregorianDate.setMilliseconds(e) }; }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using http://www.farsiweb.info/jalali/jalali.js, try

```
function printJalali(year, month, day) {
  var jalali = gregorian_to_jalali([year, month+1, day]);
  return jalali[0] + "/" + jalali[1] + "/" + jalali[2];
}

var today = new Date();
alert(printJalali(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()));
```